# Is there a way to handle popups during playback using Sahi Pro without each popup opening its own controller window?

Tags: sahi

I'm testing a list of links using Sahi Pro, and each link opens a popup window in which I have to assert that a few elements are available.  I'm able to use _closeWindow to get rid of each popup, but I've noticed that every time a new popup loads, it opens a new Sahi controller window to execute the script within that popup.  These controller windows do not close when the popups close.  Before long there are so many open controller windows that test execution freezes.

Is there a way to close these controller windows programatically?  Or to prevent a new one from accompanying each popup in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This can be avoided by running scripts as test suites from the command line.

Comment: FYI, In the coming release, Sahi Pro will no longer open multiple Controller windows.